# PostgreSQL upgrade from 9.1 to 9.3 on Red Hat Enterprise 5.9

Tags: linux, postgresql, upgrade, redhat

I have a RHEL 5.9 (64 bit) installation which is running Postgresql 9.1x database server. I need to upgrade to Postgresql 9.3 and also install PostGIS database extensions. I have looked at this one: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/329-An-almost-idiots-guide-to-install-PostgreSQL-9.3,-PostGIS-2.1-and-pgRouting-with-Yum.html

and looks like I am going to need:  http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-5-x86_64/pgdg-redhat93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm to install pg 9.3 and then do: sudo rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm to install some  packages and finally: sudo yum install postgis2_93 to install PostGIS.

While all this sounds good I need to figure out how to upgrade to 9.3 first. I thought I could try running pg_upgrade but it said command not found. I also think I have will have to add the yum.postgresql.org location to some file to enable the rpm download.

Am I on right track? Note, there is no actual database being used on the server and so either a fresh install or an upgrade will do.

**update: Problem is that I can't install any software. Please see this **: https://www.google.com/#q=yum+object+is+not+callable

Thanks!

Meengla

Comment: You must install 9.3 before you can use `pg_upgrade` to upgrade to it. See the PostgreSQL manual on upgrading for details.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the Question: I can't even install any software before I can proceed.

Comment: Don't ask to us to do a google search as our results will differ. If you get a Yum error then try asking about it on SuperUser or ServerFault as they aren't the topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Martin, I found the Yum error after I posted the original question. BTW, even the original question was attempted at SuperUser but it kept saying: Enter a Title. So I came here.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have two RHEL servers. One of them I was/is facing the problem related to the Question and that problem could not fixed until I resolve the 'yum error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable' problem whenever I try to install any updates. **For that I will ask a separate question, probably on SuperUser.**

Now, on the other server too I needed to upgrade from Postgresql 9.1 to 9.3 but that server did not have the yum error. And I successfully upgraded that server by downloading 9.3 and installing it as a separate instance and made the 9.1 instance to listen to some other port than 5432. So now 9.3 is working fine and I going to figure out how to completely remove 9.1 from the system.
Thanks.